# TensorFlow - ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_26: expected shape=(None, 2412, 3, 1), found shape=(None, 3, 1)

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction

I'm new to ML and trying to write a neural network to for prediction, but I just can't solve the ValueError. I have looked up to different answers but still get the same error. How to fix this?

X_train should be with dim (2412, 3)
y_train should be with dim (2412)

X_val should be with dim (603, 3)
y_val (603)

```
# Extract features and labels
X = training_data[['X', 'Y', 'IsUsable']].values
y = training_data[['IsDamaged']].values
​
# Extract testing data features
X_test = testing_data[['X', 'Y', 'IsUsable']].values
​
# Split data into training and validation sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
​
# Reshape data for CNN input
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
​
X_train=np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.int)
y_train=np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.int)
​
X_val=np.asarray(X_val).astype(np.int)
y_val=np.asarray(y_val).astype(np.int)
```

```
# Define CNN model
model = Sequential()
input_layer = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1],1), name="Input")
conv_layer1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', name="conv1")(input_layer)
pool_layer1 = MaxPool2D((1,1), name="pool1")(conv_layer1)
conv_layer2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', name="conv2")(pool_layer1)
pool_layer2 = MaxPool2D((1,1), name="pool2")(conv_layer2)
flatten = Flatten()(pool_layer2)
output_layer = Dense(4, activation='softmax', name="Output")(flatten)

# Compile and fit model
model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=10)
```

I tried to change the input shape but I think the code must have other bugs.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is definitely caused by the input size. The size needs to be reflective of the batches it will size, and since you tell it to expect `X_train.shape[0]` then it will expect it to have a dimension of size 2412. [The docs](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Input.html) say

> shape: A shape tuple (integers), not including the batch size. For instance, shape=(32,) indicates that the expected input will be batches of 32-dimensional vectors.`

Make the input size `Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],1),name='Input')` to resolve this particular issue.